# Is there a method to generate the complement of a context-free grammar?

Tags: finite-automata, context-free, formal-grammars

Given the languages $L_0 = {w \in \{0,1\}^*}$ such that $w$ is a palindrome and $L_1 = {w \in \{0,1\}^*}$ such that $w$ is *not* a palindrome, meaning $L_1$ is the complement of $L_0$, we want to find the grammar for both languages. $G(L_0) = S \to \epsilon | 0S0 | 1S1 | 0 | 1$ is easy to come up with, but $G(L_1)$ is much more complex.

In this case, we have the simple CFG $G_0$ and want to find the CFG $G_1$ that is its complement which can be much more complex. Is there a method to derive the complement of a CFG?

Answer (score 2):

If $L_0$ in a context-free language, this doesn't guarantee that its complement is context free. For example, consider the language
$$L_0 = \{a,b,c\}^* \setminus \{a^nb^nc^n : n \geq 0\}.$$
This language is context-free, but is complement (with respect to $\{a,b,c\}$) is not.

Another way to formulate your question is as follows: given a context-free grammar for a language $L$, is there an algorithm that either constructs a context-free grammar for the complement of $L$, or determines that the complement of $L$ is not regular? Such an algorithm can be used to decide whether the complement of $L$ is context-free. However, this is undecidable, as we now show following [Hendrik Jan's notes](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ehoogeboomhj/second/codingcomputations.pdf).

Recall that given a grammar $G$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, it is undecidable whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$. Let $\#$ be a new symbol, and construct a grammar for the language
$$ L = L_0 \# \Sigma^* \cup \Sigma^* \# L(G), $$
where $L_0$ is a context-free language whose complement is not context-free (if $|\Sigma| \geq 3$, we can use the one above, and if $|\Sigma| = 2$, we can encode $a,b,c$ as $a,ba,bba$; if $|\Sigma| = 1$ then it is easy to check whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$). If $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ then $L=\Sigma^*\#\Sigma^*$, and so the complement of $L$ is context-free. Otherwise, suppose that $w \notin L(G)$. Then
$$ \overline{L} \cap \Sigma^* \# w = (\Sigma^* \setminus L_0) \# w, $$
which is not context-free, and so $\overline{L}$ itself is not context-free (since the context-free languages are closed under intersection with a regular language). This shows that $\overline{L}$ is context-free iff $L(G) = \Sigma^*$.

The problem of deciding whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ is actually not recursively enumerable. This means that there is no algorithm which, on input $G$, halts iff $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ (however, there is a simple algorithm that halts iff $L(G) \neq \Sigma^*$, namely go over all words in $\Sigma^*$ in parallel, and check whether each of them belongs to $L(G)$). Therefore there is no algorithm that, given a context-free grammar for a language $L$, halts iff the complement of $L$ is context-free.

In other words, even the following solution to your problem does not exist: an algorithm that attempts to construct a context-free grammar for the complement of the given context-free language, and either halts with the grammar, or never halts (if the complement is not context-free).

Comment: I feel stupid, but how is that first language context-free?

Comment: That has been answered before several times.

Comment: Roughly speaking, either the word is not in $a^*b^*c^*$, or it is of the form $a^ib^jc^k$ where one of the following holds: $i>j,i<j,i>k,i<k,j>k,j<k$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. I was missing "transitivity of equality" as a hint.